# how to create objective - c class with default method implemetation?

Tags: ios, templates, overriding, viewdidload, xcode6.1

When i create new class subclass of UIViewController in ios section there is viewDidLoad method,didReceiveMemoryWarning,prepareForSegue method already implemented.

But now i want to create class with viewWillAppear,initWithTitle,viewDidLoad method by default.(means in class user don't need to type these methods).

like template in mail body by default our template implemented when ever create mail body.

can i do this with latest xcode (Create class with by default override method implementation.)?

Comment: You could probably add a custom code snippet with a class body and the needed methods to xcode:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html

Comment: check this out http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to implement a custom class and use every where by extends to that class